# Working with TFS offline and then going back online

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When the TFS server is down and developers work offline, when the server comes back up will it be business as usual even though they made local changes?

Will it just be a pending change at that point?

Answer (score 2):

When you go offline you can carry on working on your files. When you go back online it will check to see if anyone has checked in/out the files that you have been working on.

If none of them have changed, it will check them out for you and you carry on as normal.
If someone has checked in/out then you will have to attempt to merge the files either at that point or on check-in. Sometimes this will auto-merge, others you'll have to do it yourself.

How big a problem this is depends on how many overlapping files are going to be edited. Merging can be a pain, so I'd try to keep that server offline for a short time if possible. If you're using them, avoid changing auto-generated content, such as a Linq2Sql .dbml file as these can be a nightmare to merge.

Comment: The process is also markedly different between Local workspaces and Server workspaces. Server workspaces have a distinct "Go Offline/Go Online" command. Local workspaces are offline by default and sync on checkin/get latest so to speak.